# Meteor app not running in iOS Simulator after upgrading to El Capitán

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

I was having a problem with not being able to login through Xcode iOS Simulator after upgrading to El Capitán for my Meteor app. I reinstalled Xcode, but that didn't seem to help.

I then removed my cordova plugins from my Meteor app (cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1, ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.0.4), cleared .meteor/local/cordova-plugins, then went to re-test my app:

```
Marks-MacBook-Air:meteor markshust$ meteor run ios-device --settings settings/dev.json --verbose
Adding platform iOS to Cordova project
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding platform iOS to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform ios
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   Error: version not found: cordova-ios@3.9.2
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:270:25
   at _rejected (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
   at Promise.when (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

So, I went ahead and installed cordova-ios and ios-deploy:

```
Marks-MacBook-Air:meteor markshust$ npm install -g cordova-ios ios-deploy
-
> ios-deploy@1.8.2 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
> ./src/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild

=== BUILD TARGET ios-deploy OF PROJECT ios-deploy WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies

Write auxiliary files
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-project-headers.hmap
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy.hmap
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.LinkFileList
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-generated-files.hmap
write-file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-all-target-headers.hmap

CompileC build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.o src/ios-deploy.c normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=214 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/zf/wj73wl2d71z5d7n2bdrw78mh0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-generated-files.hmap -I/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-own-target-headers.hmap -I/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/ios-deploy-project-headers.hmap -I/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/include -I/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/DerivedSources -F/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release -x objective-c -fno-objc-arc -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.d --serialize-diagnostics /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.dia -c /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/src/ios-deploy.c -o /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.o

Ld build/Release/ios-deploy normal x86_64
    cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release -F/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release -filelist /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -framework MobileDevice -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -framework CoreFoundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ios-deploy_dependency_info.dat -o /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy

GenerateDSYMFile build/Release/ios-deploy.dSYM build/Release/ios-deploy
    cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy -o /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy.dSYM

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

/usr/local/bin/ios-deploy -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
cordova-ios@3.9.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova-ios

ios-deploy@1.8.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
```

However, after I installed those two packages, I'm getting the same error:

```
Marks-MacBook-Air:meteor markshust$ meteor run ios-device --settings settings/dev.json --verbose
Adding platform iOS to Cordova project
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding platform iOS to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform ios
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   Error: version not found: cordova-ios@3.9.2
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:270:25
   at _rejected (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
   at Promise.when (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
   at /Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush (/Users/markshust/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12lm5ls++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

Anyone have any clue what is going on? It is complaining that it can't find version cordova-ios@3.9.2, but it's obviously installed globally.

I also tried uninstalling the global packages:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova-ios ios-deploy
```

then removing & adding back ios to meteor platform:

```
meteor remove-platform ios
meteor add-platform ios
```

but I'm still receiving the same error:

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform iOS to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch platform ios
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   Error: version not found: cordova-ios@3.9.2
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is  temporary maybe. Try `meteor add-platform ios@3.9.1` in the meantime.

Comment: While adding platforms:
error: ios@3.9.1: no such platform

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i was having the same issue, just deleting the .cordova directory fixes it

```
rm -rf ~/.cordova
```

Comment: You may need to use `sudo` with the above command in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I just started having the same issue a couple hours ago.
I was able to work around this by blowing away my `${HOME}/.cordova` directory which appears to keep a cache of previously downloaded versions of `cordova-ios`.  I had a 3.9.1 version in there (not a 3.9.2) version.  After deleting that directory and redoing the `cordova platform add iOS` command, everything worked fine.  I can't explain why that worked...  but hopefully it will get other people back to working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue after running on the real device, simply unplugging my phone from laptop helped. There is open [issue here](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/332)